# How to write an algorithm like under figure in latex?

Tags: algorithms

How to write an algorithm like under figure in latex?
[image]

I executed this cod, but the output of the algorithm was not like the above figure

```
\usepackage[options ]{algorithm2e}
\begin{algorithm}‎
\SetAlgoLined‎
\SetKwInOut{Step}{Step}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\Input{The }
\Output{The }‎
\For{Num}{
\Step{Choose}‎
\Step{Choose}
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\caption{To }
\end{algorithm}‎
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This site doesn't do well with "please make this figure for me".  Have you looked into how to create algorithm diagrams?  What have you found?  There are several links under the "Related" heading in the side bar of this page, do those help?

Comment: As [already asked you on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77022758/write-an-algorithm-like-figure-in-latex#comment135781818_77022758), please show what you tried and which problems you face.

Comment: I executed this cod, but the output of the algorithm was not like the above figure

Comment: @Yas Please add which packages you use.

Comment: \usepackage[options ]{algorithm2e}

Comment: \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

Comment: Welcome. // @Yas, please learn right from the start to do better when posting code (which we expect anyway). Your code can't compile once we copied it. Just compare your snippet with the full code, omitting the documents content. This will improve both answers and will result in less comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\caption{To} 
\SetKwInOut{Step}{Step}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\Input{The}
\Output{The}
\For{Num}{
\par\textbf{Step 1:} Choose
\par\textbf{Step 2:} Choose
\par\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that it does not look like the picture.

Comment: step-1.1step-1.2,...

Comment: Try instead `{Step-1.1:}` etc. ...